# 3D plot linear regression pylab

Tags: python, 3d, matplotlib

I need to plot a linear regression problem with 2 features. So I think in this case instead of a line I need a hyperplane to separate my data. I have already done that for one feature but dont have any idea for this case.

this my plot for dataset with 300 samples and 1 feature.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: ANY IDEA? IS IT SOME KINDE OF WIERD QUESTION ::D !?

Comment: Is your question about fitting a 2d plane in 3d-space to your data? Or is it about visualization of the plane? Or do you really want to separate some classes of data, as you say in your question?

Comment: Sorry! but a 3D regression is what you are talking about !? Please make question a bit clear... And have you got what you wanted from the following answer... ?

Answer (score 3):

Check the numpy [meshgrid](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) and the [plot_surface](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) methods

Try running this sample code and changing it to your liking

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig=plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[1,3,5,6,8]
z=[3,3,5,6,7]
x, y= np.meshgrid(x,y)


ax.plot_surface(x,y,z)

plt.show()
```

I hope it helps